# Process.Start() and cmd produce different outputs

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, process, sqlite

I need to perform SQLite database dump into another database file. For this I am planning to use [SQLite Command Shell](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) as I would really love to avoid ADO.NET stuff. The script I need to launch is fairly simple:

```
sqlite3 "C:\path\to\input.db" .dump | sqlite3 "C:\path\to\dump.db"
```

(`sqlite3` here is SQLite Command Shell executable itself)

So, firstly, to check how everything goes I tested it in `cmd.exe`. It works fine, provides no console output and finishes in a couple of seconds which is really nice.

Now, I would like a C# method to do the very same thing. Here is what I do:

```
    public void Dump(string sqlitePath, string inputPath, string dumpPath)
    {
        Process sqlite = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = sqlitePath,
                Arguments = $"\"{inputPath}\" .dump | \"{sqlitePath}\" \"{dumpPath}\""
            }
        };
        sqlite.Start();
        sqlite.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Now, this results in command line window showing up with `sqlite3` output in it.
This output basically looks like follows:

```
...
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1117,64,45.0,-104.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1118,55,45.0,-103.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1119,42,45.0,-102.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1120,42,45.0,-101.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1121,42,45.0,-100.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1122,38,45.0,-99.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1123,47,45.0,-98.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1124,40,45.0,-97.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1125,37,45.0,-96.0);
INSERT INTO "myTable" VALUES(1126,34,45.0,-95.0);
...
```

which is obviously a dump log. Now, this has side effects: when running this way, the operation takes forever. I presume this is because the output being printed takes the most of the time.

Now, the questions are:

1. Why do I get output when running the application with `Process.Start` and get nothing when running it with `cmd.exe`?
2. How do I reach the same behaviour as "native" `cmd.exe` execution?

**UPDATE 1**

Also, I tried to reach this bevahiour by executing `cmd.exe` instead of `sqlite3` so that my code would look like follows:

```
    public void Dump(string sqlitePath, string inputPath, string dumpPath)
    {
        Process sqlite = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"\"{sqlitePath}\" \"{inputPath}\" .dump | \"{sqlitePath}\" \"{dumpPath}\""
            }
        };
        sqlite.Start();
        sqlite.WaitForExit();
    }
```

This results in cmd window being displayed with no output. It points to some folder (nothing related to files used here) and basically looks like no arguments have been passed into it (it accepts user input etc). It also never closes. Am I somehow misusing `cmd` syntax?

**UPDATE 2**

Got it working with this:

```
    public void Dump(string sqlitePath, string inputPath, string dumpPath)
    {
        Process sqlite = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"/c \" \"{sqlitePath}\" \"{inputPath}\" .dump | \"{sqlitePath}\" \"{dumpPath}\" \""
            }
        };
        sqlite.Start();
        sqlite.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Note `/c` and extra quotes in the arguments list.

Comment: Your working code is using a pipe between two processes, and this pipe is handled by `cmd.exe`. You need to code all the logic to replicate the `cmd` handling, OR, you can call `cmd` and let it handle the pipe.

Comment: @MCND I have updated the question, please check it out.

Comment: Your final command (what will be executed) should be something like `cmd.exe /c" ""x:\somewhere\sqlite.exe"" ""C:\path\to\input.db"" .dump | ""x:\somewhere\sqlite.exe"" ""C:\path\to\dump.db"" "`.

Comment: @MCND `/c` did the trick, thank you!